# Filtering a set of Either[x, y], with logging

Tags: scala, functional-programming, either

Given a `Set[Either[BadObject, GoodObject]]`, I'd like to convert it into a `Set[GoodObject]`, while logging all the `BadObjects`.

The problem I am having is that when I try to add logging in a `collect` call, like:

```
someMethodThatReurnsTheSet.collect {
  case Right(value) => value
  case Left(res) => logger.warn(s"Bad object : $res")
}
```

This changes the return value and I am getting a `Set[None]`, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple way:

```
someMethodThatReurnsTheSet().collect {
  case Right(value) => Some(value)
  case Left(res) => 
    logger.warn(s"Bad object : $res")
    None
}.flatten
```

---

many alternatives are possible, for instance or see the other answers :)

```
val (lefts, rights) = someMethodThatReurnsTheSet().partition(_.isLeft)
lefts.foreach(err => logger.warn(s"Bad object : ${err.left.get}"))
val set = rights.map(_.right.get)
```

Comment: You can replace `collect`/`flatten` by a `flatMap`. The `collect` here is a `map` really since it handles all cases. And then `map`/`flatten` can simply be a `flatMap`. `Set(Right(1), Left("s"), Left(s"x"), Right(4)).flatMap { case Right(x) => Some(x); case Left(x) => println(x); None }`

Answer (score 6):

Try [`partition`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Set.html#partition(p:A=%3EBoolean):(C,C)) in combination with [chaining](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/ChainingOps.html)

```
import util.chaining._

someMethodThatReurnsTheSet
  .partition(_.isRight)
  .tap { case (_, lefts) => logger.warn(s"Bad objects $lefts") }
  .pipe { case (rights, _) => rights }
```

Comment: Should mention this is only for Scala 2.13.*

Answer (score 5):

Another way using `foldLeft`:

```
someMethodThatReturnsTheSet.foldLeft(Set.empty[GoodObject]) {
   case (acc, goodOrBad) => goodOrBad match {
     case Right(good) => acc + good
     case Left(bad) => 
       logger.warn("Bad object: $bad")
       acc
   }
}
```

If you don't mind allocating:

```
someMethodThatReturnsTheSet.flatMap {
  case Right(good) => Set(good)
  case Left(bad) => 
    logger.warn("Bad object: $bad")
    Set.empty
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take an action only in the `Left`-case, you can use `.left.foreach`:

```
setOfEithers.flatMap { e =>
    e.left.foreach { bad => logger.warn(s"Bad object: $bad") }
    e.toOption
}
```